# How to rebuild object with keys and values javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking for your advise how to re-build object in javascript/jquery? Im receiving JSON from server

Source json (var array):

```
{  
  "key1":{  
         "subkey1":"a",
         "subkey2":"b",
      },
  "key2":{  
         "subkey1":"a",
         "subkey2":"a",
      }
}
```

Expected object:

```
{  
  "a":{  
         "subkey1":[
                      "key1",
                      "key2",
                   ],
         "subkey2":[
                      "key2"
                   ]
      },
  "b":{  
         "subkey2":[
                      "key1"
                   ]
      }
}
```

Here is where I got stuck:

```
    var newarray = {};
    for (var key in array) {
        var items = [];
        for (var item_id in array[key]) {
            items.push(item_id);
            newarray[array[key][item_id]] = [];
        }
        console.log(items);
    }
    console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: You do not have a multi-dimensional array.  You have an object with nested sub-objects. `[]` denotes an array.  `{}` denotes an object.

Comment: The objects represented by subkey1, subkey2 are invalid.

Comment: Given that array keys are numeric, and your object keys are not numeric, it's unclear how you want to translate this to a true multi-dimensional array construct.

Comment: Do you mean `"subkey1": ["key1", "key2"]`?

Comment: Hello guys, yes, please take my apologies. It should be [ ]

Comment: Bottom left of the question there is an `edit` link you can use to fix issues with.

Comment: Perhaps you are feeling more like a "dictionary" but thinking in terms of an array. - WWC

Comment: the expected output is invalid

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the PHP-style method:

```js
var newArray = {};

for (var key in array) {
    for (var subKey in array[key]) {
        var val = array[key][subKey];
        
        if (!(val in newArray)) {
            newArray[val] = {};
        }

        if (!(subKey in newArray[val])) {
            newArray[val][subKey] = [];
        }

        newArray[val][subKey].push(key);
    }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach and store the target object and the path for the next recursive call.

If no more object is found take the value and all keys as well as the actual key and generate a new property in an new object. Proceed for any other properties in the object.

The wuestion does not states the value of the inversed object. This approach assigns `undefined` to all leaves properties.

```js
function setValue(object, keys, value) {
    var last = keys.pop(),
        target = keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object);

    target[last] = target[last] || [];
    target[last].push(value);
}

function inverse(source, target = {}, path = []) {
    Object.entries(source).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') return inverse(v, target, [k, ...path]);
        setValue(target, [v, k, ...path.slice(0, -1)], ...path.slice(-1));
    });
    return target;
}

var object = { key1: { subkey1: 'a', subkey2: 'b'}, key2: { subkey1: 'a', subkey2: 'a' } },
   inversed = inverse(object);
   
console.log(inversed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try (where r={})

```
Object.entries(d).map(([k,x])=> Object.entries(x).map( ([s,a]) => (
  r[a]=r[a]||{}, r[a][s]=(r[a][s]||[]).concat(k)
)))
```

```js
let d={  
  "key1":{  
         "subkey1":"a",
         "subkey2":"b",
      },
  "key2":{  
         "subkey1":"a",
         "subkey2":"a",
      }
}

let r= {}

Object.entries(d).map( ([k,x])=> Object.entries(x).map( ([s,a]) => (
  r[a]=r[a]||{}, r[a][s]=(r[a][s]||[]).concat(k)
)))


console.log(r);
```

Comment: I would hunt down and kill the dev (bare hands) who left this in a codebase I was maintaining

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - at the very very least, you could use _somewhat_ meaningful variable names. Or are you trying to code golf?

Comment: k=key, s=subkey, a=letters a,b

Comment: Why not use `key` and `subkey` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = {
  "key1": {
    "subkey1": 'a',
    "subkey2": 'b',
  },
  "key2": {
    "subkey1": 'a',
    "subkey2": 'a',
  }
};

let expected = {
  "a": {
    "subkey1": {
      key1: true,
      key2: true,
    },
    "subkey2": {
      key2: true
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "subkey2": {
      key1: true
    }
  }
};

let output = {};
Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, subObj]) => {
  Object.entries(subObj).forEach(([subKey, value]) => {
    output[value] = output[value] || {};
    output[value][subKey] = output[value][subKey] || {};
    output[value][subKey][key] = true;
  });
});

console.log(expected);
console.log(output);
```